# How to add a regression line for the entire data in seaborn.lmplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot the scatter plot in which each point is colored w.r.t the variable `Points`. Moreover, I want to add the regression line.

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
import seaborn as sns

decathlon = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Deep-Learning/main/decathlon.txt", sep='\t')

g = sns.lmplot(
    data = decathlon,
    x="100m", y="Long.jump",
    hue = 'Points', palette = 'viridis'
)
```

[image]

It seems to me that there are 2 regression lines, one for each group of the data. This is not what I want. I would like to have a regression line for the entire data. Moreover, how can I hide the legend on the right hand side?

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `lmplot` unless you need to use a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) to split your dataset in several subplots.

Since the example that you show does not use any of the functionalities provided by `FacetGrid`, you should instead create your plot using a combination of `scatterplot()` and `regplot()`

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day")
sns.regplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", scatter=False, ax=ax)
```

[image]